# Check if a bool variable is initialized in c#

Tags: c#, boolean

So I have a bool variable like this in model.

```
bool Foo;
```

I am receiving data from server and de-serialize it model object. So whatever fields are not there in server data gets initialized to defaults. And `default(bool)` is false.

But value `false` is also an acceptable value for my variable `Foo`. So is there some way to check if it gets value `false` from server or its default.

I also have same issue with other types like int, double etc. which doesn't defaults to null.

Comment: Have you considered using `bool?` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell On deserialization, would the value be null and not false if not sent from server? Just want to confirm once.

Comment: Yes, null if not explicitly assigned a non-null value

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your place, I'd use `Nullable<bool>` (`bool?`) to your purposes. Then you will be able to check value in this way:

```
bool? Foo;

if(Foo.HasValue)
{
   // do something with Foo.Value
}
else
{
   // Foo is uninitialized
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I didn't know of that. Now I have to change my whole code for making int, double etc this way :(

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.3190.0) the accepted answer isn't complete: compiler error. Just need to initialize to null variable declaration. so:

```
bool? Foo = null;

if (Foo.HasValue)
{
    // do something with Foo.Value 
}
else
{
    // Foo is uninitialized
}
```